# Odd behavior of Windows thread

Tags: c, multithreading, while-loop, gtk, winsock

I am combining GTK+, WinAPI and Winsock to create a graphical client-server interface, a waiting room. `nUsers` is a variable that determines the number of clients successfully connected.

Within a Windows thread, created by:

```
CreateThread(NULL, 0, action_to_users, NULL, 0, NULL);
```

I use the do-nothing while loop so that it freezes until a user connects.

```
while(!nUsers);
```

---

However, it never passes through the loop as if `nUsers` never becomes > 0.`nUsers` counts the number of clients connected properly, as I constantly monitor it and use it in a variety of different functions.
To prove my point, something even stranger happens.
If I make the loop

```
while(!nUsers) { printf("(%i)\n", nUsers); }
```

To spam the console with text printed out (doesn't matter what text as long as it is not an empty string) it works as intended.

---

What could be possibly going on here...

Comment: Mark `nUsers` `volatile`.

Comment: @orhtej2 You are genuis. It worked.. but why..

Comment: I mean I am a qualified C programmer, I know where to use volatile, but now it didn't look like the situation I know of

Comment: 'while(!nUsers);' a room heater.  Windows has plenty synchro options that require less A/C, (and does not completely waste a core).

Comment: @MartinJames what do you mean?
I should admit that I am new to windows threading. I rely on the function reference.. and I have entirely read it.

Comment: @Corelation You 'do nothing' loop does something.  It uses 100% of a complete execution core, and it uses up inter-core memory bandwidth while 'doing nothing'.  Besides wasting CPU/memory resources that would be better used 'doing somethig useful', is uses a lot of power and you may well hear your cooling fans speed up a notch, in the manner of a fan heater:(   Perhpas not unsurprisingly, your OS provides synchronization mechanisms to allow efficient inter-thread signaling without CPU-looping.  You shoud search MSDN/Google for 'events and 'semaphores'.

Comment: Incidentally. while it worked 'for you' in this case, 'volatile' is not guaranteed effective even for the (bad) polling operation/s you are doing.  Google/MSDN for 'CriticalSection'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the original problem: compiler is free to cache the value of `nUsers` since the variable is not modified within this loop. Marking the variable `volatile` prevents this optimization as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/246392/7034621).

Regarding what you're trying to achieve - it looks like a producer-consumer pattern, where the thread(s) handling the sockets are producers and your GUI thread is a consumer. You can slow down your consumer loop to only loop when new data is available using:

- [semaphores as showcased here](http://icarus.cs.weber.edu/~dab/cs3100/post/chap.06/bb.cpp) - producer thread increments count on semaphore while consumer decrements it upon dequeing work item.
- [Events like here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43194070/7034621) - producer thread signals an event while consumer thread waits for it to become signalled. You can queue the work in some queue to allow more than one item being processed.
- [Condition variables (XP+)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686903(v=vs.85).aspx) - here a variable you're waiting for gets signalled upon meeting certain criteria.

Comment: 'where the thread(s) handling the sockets are producers and your GUI thread is a consumer' - if that is the case, then neither the OP's original 'loop doing nothing' or our suggestions of events'semas/condvar waits are useful - one cannot wait in a GUI event handler.  The go-to API for comms in that case is PostMessage(), or possibly PostThreadMessage().